Is there a way in Angular to have a CanDeactivate guard only trigger on Back button navigate
I'm looking to have a CanDeactivate guard only fire on Back button navigation and not upon clicking a link. I have an unrouted section of my application that I'd like to enable back button navigation for, so I'd like to deactivate the back button and then change the view instead.
I've tried filtering on event.type === 'popstate', then using history.pushState and location.go but those don't seem to work - navigation away still occurs.
I was considering having a service that captures router events and holds the past event type in a BehaviorSubject. Wondering if there will be concurrency issues with that when accessed from the guard.

Have you tried it with HostBinding
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])    onPopState(event) {     console.log('Back button pressed');    }

Thanks for the reply! How would I integrate this into the candeactivate? If I have a behaviorsubject with the last event, I'd have the same concurrency issues I think...

Just try putting that previous code on canDeactivate guard and import the neccessary modules

Hey just following up to say that it worked like a charm, thanks! Feel free to post as answer

Hello, nice to hear that it worked out for you, i will post it as answer now.... feel free to mark it as solved

The solution would be using HostListener, something as below:
 @HostListener('window:popstate',['$event'])
 onPopState(event) {
     console.log('Back button pressed');    
 }

